# image suddenly not loading anymore

Tags: reactjs, truffle, ipfs

I am working on decentragram. This was working fine a few days ago but now image not load anymore. Giving error as bafybeieq6nyhu7ilorb7dxepo6sexab6oqigkjhzc62dxio6x5xaurge7u.ipfs.infura-ipfs.io/:1   GET https://bafybeieq6nyhu7ilorb7dxepo6sexab6oqigkjhzc62dxio6x5xaurge7u.ipfs.infura-ipfs.io/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

This is how I Displayed image in main.js

```
 <ul id="imageList" className="list-group list-group-flush">
                  <li className="list-group-item">
                    <p className="text-center"><img src={ 'https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/${image.hash}' } style={{ maxWidth: '420px'}}/></p>
                    <p>{image.description}</p>
                  </li>
```

and in App.js

```
const ipfsClient = require('ipfs-http-client')
const ipfs = ipfsClient({ host: 'ipfs.infura.io', port: 5001, protocol: 'https' }) // leaving out the arguments will default to these values
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, It worked after I replaced the url with this

```
<p className="text-center"><img src={`https://gateway.ipfs.io/ipfs/${image.hash}`} style={{ maxWidth: '420px'}}/></p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much man! Finally after 3-4days, this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

in JavaScript template should can be used with ` `${var_name}``
so if we use like '${var_name}' or  "${var_name}" then it will be read ${var_name} as string hardcoded.
so you should use

```
<p className="text-center"><img src{`https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/${image.hash}` } style={{ maxWidth: '420px'}}/></p>
```

then you will be able to get the value of the variable 

ref:  [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)